# Woocommerce Restrict My Account Page but NOT Lost Password Page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I have a WordPress site with Woocommerce. In Woocommerce, Lost Password URL merges with My Account page `(www.site.com/my-account/lost-password/)`.

Then I create a redirect function that will redirect non-logged in users when they hit "My Account" page to "Login" page. This means I limit them too to access the Lost Password page.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'redirect' );
function redirect() {
  if ( is_page(array('my-account', 'payment-screen', 'submit-resume', 'post-a-job')) && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
      wp_redirect( home_url('/login') );
      die();
  } elseif ( is_page(array( 'register', 'login' )) && is_user_logged_in() ) {
      wp_redirect( home_url('/my-account') );
      die();
  }
}
```

I want to restrict non-logged in users only for `www.site.com/my-account/` and redirect them to `www.site.com/login/` but NOT `www.site.com/my-account/lost-password/`. How can I do that?

Comment: On your `lost-password` page set parent to `no-parent`

Comment: @SaadSuri Where I can find lost-password page? I don't see that page in my site, I guess Woocommerce directly provide them in templates file.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve on this way:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'class_to_login_page', 20 );
function class_to_login_page(){
  global $post;
  global $wp;
  $request = explode( '/', $wp->request );
  $page_id = get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id');
  if(!is_user_logged_in() && $post->ID == (icl_object_id($page_id, 'page')) && end($request) !== 'lost-password'){
    wp_redirect( home_url('/login') );
    exit;
  }
}
```

I check if user is logged, if the ID is equal for my-account page and if is not the lost-password endpoint.
I hope this help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found a solution.
First, create a new shortcode for the lost password. Use this code in *function.php*:

```
function wc_custom_lost_password_form( $atts ) {
    return wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-lost-password.php', array( 'form' => 'lost_password' ) );
}
add_shortcode( 'lost_password_form', 'wc_custom_lost_password_form' );
```

Create a new page and use this shortcode [lost_password_form].
Now change your lost password page by using this code in *function.php*:

```
function reset_pass_url() {
    $siteURL = get_option('siteurl');
    return "{$siteURL}/page-name";
}
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'reset_pass_url', 11, 0 );
```